# Unable to start services using homebrew

Tags: homebrew

MacOs 10.15.1
Ruby 2.4.4
Homebrew 2.1.16

I am currently experiencing issues when attempting to start any services through Homebrew. 
Output for any attempt is as follows:

```
$ brew services start postgresql@9.5
Error: undefined method `resolve_alias' for Formula:Class
/usr/local/bin/brew-services.rb:154:in `service'
/usr/local/bin/brew-services.rb:203:in `check'
/usr/local/bin/brew-services.rb:193:in `run!'
/usr/local/bin/brew-services.rb:397:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:79:in `require'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:79:in `require?'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:108:in `<main>'
```

Edit 11/27/19:
Brew Doctor output

```
$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  php
```

Comment: Do you have many other brew installs?  Did you do any brew updates or upgrades recently?  Did this ever work?

Comment: Not at all related to Rails, only related to Ruby because of brew, unrelated to the Postgres package, and belongs on superuser or serverfault.

Comment: What does `brew doctor` output?

Comment: lacostenycoder
I have never attempted to run services through Homebrew before however I am working on a project and try to stay as close to the methods being used by the other members of my team as possible.

MikeHeft
Added the brew doctor output.

Answer (score 0):

This error was resolved by removing /usr/local/bin/brew-services.rb

Comment: Sometimes `brew update` can automatically fix versions (in cases where that file isn't the culprit).